# Remove duplicate data-frame in a list, while the first row is different

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a list of dataframes, and I want to remove the duplicates if (2nd row - last row) are the same.

df = [df1,df2]

Despite the first row are different, the rest are the same. Therefore, I want to remove either df_1 OR df_2

I have tried 'drop_duplicate', but it doesn't work

```
id df_1
1   0.5
2   0.5

id df_2
1   0.5
2   0.5


df=[]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0.5], [2, 0.5]]),
                   columns=['id', 'df_1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0.5], [2, 0.5]]),
                   columns=['id', 'df_2'])

df.append(df1)
df.append(df2)


unique = pd.Series(df).drop_duplicates().tolist()

print(unique)
```

Comment: You are trying to use a list as a dataframe. Instead, you can use `pd.concat` to merge the dataframes. Also, in what sense the first rows are different? The examples are the same.

Comment: This is a correlation calculation, and I simply use a for loop to calcuate it. Eventually, I have the correlations series of (A&B) AND (B&A). The time column and correlation figures are the same. Yet, the headers are different

Answer (score 1):

One of your issues if you want to stack your dataframes is the fact that you have different column names, so concatenating might be tricky. Here is a suggestion on how to bypass this. First, make a list of your dataframes:

```
df_list = [
    pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0.5], [2, 0.5]]),
                   columns=['id', 'df_1']),
    pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0.5], [2, 0.5]]),
                   columns=['id', 'df_2'])
]
```

then do the following:

```
df_new = np.concatenate([df.values for df in df_list])
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_new)
```

This will give you:

```
    0    1
0  1.0  0.5
1  2.0  0.5
2  1.0  0.5
3  2.0  0.5
```

Give the resulting dataframe `df_new` a new column name:

```
df_new.columns =['index','Col_new']
```

which gives

```
 index  Col_new
0    1.0      0.5
1    2.0      0.5
2    1.0      0.5
3    2.0      0.5
```

and drop the duplicate rows:

```
df_new.drop_duplicates()
```

which gives

```
index  Col_new
0    1.0      0.5
1    2.0      0.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, my original codes are used for calculation in different currency pairs. What I have currently are 2 dataframes 

correlationship between (AUD/USD & EUR/USD) AND (EUR/USD & AUD/USD). Therefore, my first row are different, yet the correlations are the same, and I want to drop one of them. So, it is impossible for me to merge them together and remove it.

More importantly, I will add more securities on the codes.

Comment: Can you add mock-up columns to your example, so I may try to find an appropriate answer?